# How to add duplicate values to a dictionary key?

Tags: python

```
N = int(input("Number of items:"))
order_list = {}

for _ in range(N):
    item_name, price = input().split()
    order_list[item_name] = [price]
    if "item_list" == order_list[item_name]:
        order_list[item_name].append(price)
    
print(order_list)
```

I want to add input as follows:

```
input:
banana 10
grapes 20
banana 10
```

I want the output:

```
{'banana' : [10, 10], 'grapes': [20]}
```

But I can figure out how to add another `10` to the array in `'banana'`.

Comment: read about [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually check if the key is already there or not, But why not to utilize `defaultdict` from `collections`

```
from collections import defaultdict
N = int(input("Number of items:"))
order_list = []
for _ in range(N):
    order_list.append(input().split())
print(order_list)

orders = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in order_list:
    orders[k].append(v)
```

Sample Run:

```
Number of items:>? 5
Apple 2
Banana 3
Banana 4
Apple 9
Grapes 1
[['Apple', '2'], ['Banana', '3'], ['Banana', '4'], ['Apple', '9'], ['Grapes', '1']]

>>dict(orders)
{'Apple': ['2', '9'], 'Banana': ['3', '4'], 'Grapes': ['1']}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

- first check to see if the item_name is already part of the order
- if yes, append the price to it
- if not, create a new list with the first item

```
N = int(input("Number of items:"))
order_list = {}

for _ in range(N):
    item_name, price = input().split()
    if item_name in order_list:
        order_list[item_name].append(price)
    else:
        order_list[item_name] = [price]
    
print(order_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the item already exists :

```py
N = int(input("Number of items:"))
order_list = {}

for _ in range(N):
    item_name, price = input().split()
    if item_name in order_list: # if item already exists
        order_list[item_name].append(int(price))
    else:
        order_list[item_name] = [int(price)]        
print(order_list)
```

For your input, the result is : `{'banana': [10, 10], 'grapes': [20]}`